# What does "Ethernet PHY Layer 0 Present" mean in TM4C123's datasheet?

Tags: tm4c123g

I was looking for MCUs that have Ethernet capabilities (ethernet controller) built in.  I came across the [datasheet of TM4C123GH6PM](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/spms376e/spms376e.pdf?ts=1656399248955&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) MCU, which talks about the  "EPHY0" bit in one of its registers, which indicates whether the "Ethernet PHY layer 0 is present or not".

A screenshot of that register/page:

[image: EPHY0 Ethernet PHY Layer 0 Present]

I do not understand what this means. I looked it up and I know that the TM4C123 does [not have Ethernet capabilities](https://forum.43oh.com/topic/7646-energia-013-ethernet-example-doesnt-compile/?do=findComment&comment=62041), but what does this EPHY0 bit do? Does allow you to connect an Ethernet controller externally? (Is there such a thing?)

Comment: It means nothing. There’s no ethernet. Probably a cut n paste error or the register exists to support other members of the family which actually do have ethernet.

Comment: @Kartman It's most certianly not a mistake: this bit is part of a register called "device capabilities". Most likely this bit is simply at 0 on this part to indicate there is no ethernet available. Funnily enough, however, I have been unable to find another part from the Tiva series where this register exists and there is ethernet available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a register you can read if something is present in the MCU. If you read the register, it would likely indicate to you that no Ethernet features are present in the MCU.

Comment: Not likely - definitely. See that it's read-only with default value 0.